# How can I print unicode symbols within a certain range?

Tags: java, for-loop, unicode

I am trying to make a program which prints all Unicode symbols \u6000 through \u7000(1000 symbols). My program prints 50 characters, starts a new line, prints 50 more, etc. (no issue there).

I know how to print Unicode symbols, but I am not sure how to print them incrementally (adding 1 each time). Here is my program:

```
public class UnicodePrinter {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 6000; i<7000; i++) {
            if(i%50 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print("\u"+i); //issue here, see below
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on my print statement, where I typed `"\u"+i` saying "Invalid unicode" because `\u` is not completed with numbers, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just generate the `char`s directly, like this:

```
public class UnicodePrinter {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for (char i = '\u6000'; i < '\u7000'; i++) {
            if (i % 50 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.print(i); //issue here, see below
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, with only one flaw being the values used in the loop

Comment: One problem with the code could be that your console font does not support the unicode characters needed. In that case you could print out the characters into an (UTF-8 encoded) file

Comment: @KevinAnderson Good answer, and simple. I did not know I could use `char` in a `for` loop. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: One can use char in loop, but it must be avoided unless necessory, as it can't store -ve values, thats why there is 'short' type.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it to a char after converting it to a hex:

```
for (int i = 6000; i<7000; i++) {
    if(i%50 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(i), 16);
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I tried running your code and it only prints question marks.

Comment: I get the same output - are those not the right characters. We checked it against: `System.out.println("\u6000");` I think this output is correct.

Comment: oops, my bad. that is correct, thank you for your answer

Comment: No problem. glad I could help.

Comment: It is wrong in many aspects.  The most obvious one: how many codepoints are there between `\u6000` and `\u7000` ?  And, how many have you printed?

Comment: @AdrianShum good point - 1000 values printed, but there are 4096 codepoints in the range.

Comment: Why not just iterate over the given range instead of this weird and completely unnecessary hex conversion.

Comment: The other answer actually does the work correctly and cleanly.  It is pointless to use `int` in the loop while `char` is a valid integral type.  And, there is no point doing those string conversion and parsing...

Comment: @theProgrammer101 - if you get a chance please mark Kevin's answer as the accepted answer. He's fixed it.